# variable definition problem over sets in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

My problem is with the definition of variable 'ds' used in equation 1. Eq 1 runs for each line. And each line has ns (ns is a parameter) number of steps. Variable 'ds' should be defined for each step in each line.
Defined set l and nsl. parameter 'linen' shows the line number in the network. Kept equal number of steps for each line i.e ns=250.
Defined variable ds(l,nsl). Now the usage of this variable in the equation is very important. I have written this like ds(fdata(i,j,'linen'),nsl)) for the line number 'linen' and nsl for step number. Summation runs over nsl.
Error 121: 'Set expected' in ds(fdata(i,j,'linen'),nsl)) in eq1.

Could anyone help me with the definition of variable 'ds' in such situations? Please let me know if you need any more information.

```
Set
i 'Gas network buses' / 1*7 /
slack(i) 'Source bus' / 1, 3 /
t 'Time period' / t1*t1 /
mn 'Set to access fdata from excel sheet' /Cjj,Fgmin,Fgmax, linen/
l 'number of Gas lines' /1*6/
nsl 'steps' /1*250/ ;


Alias (i,j);

$call gdxxrw MultiEnergySystemData.xlsx par=fdata rng=ModifiedNGSystem!A21:F27 cDim=1 rDim=2

*=== Now import data from GDX
Parameter fdata(i,j, mn);
$gdxin MultiEnergySystemData.gdx
$load fdata
$gdxin
display data

Parameter ns /250/;


$ontext
fdata is like this
i j Cjj Fgmin Fgmax linen
1 2 50.6 0 3000 1
2 3 50.1 0 1000 2
3 4 45.3 0 10   3
2 5 45.3 0 2500 4
5 6 43.1 0 1200 5
6 7 37.5 0 600  6

$offtext

Parameter cx(i,j), cxv(i,j);
cx(i,j)$(fdata(i,j,'Cjj'))= 1;



Variables ds(l,nsl), fg(i,j);


Equation eq1;

eq1(i,j)$cx(i,j)..
fg(i,j) =e= fdata(i,j,'Fgmin') + sum(nsl,(1/ns)*(fdata(i,j,'Fgmax')-fdata(i,j,'Fgmin'))*ds(fdata(i,j,'linen'),nsl));
```

Comment: Hi! Are you new to GAMS? Is the ds a variable to be decided by the model or is it a parameter you want to calculate as a preprocessing applied to the raw data? Variables and equations are associated with mathematical models in GAMS: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GAMSPrograms.html#UG_GAMSPrograms_OrganizationOfGAMSPrograms

Comment: Thank you Raquel for your answer. The problem is solved.